# Gear S is not sending data via POST request without any error message

Tags: jquery, ajax, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am developing an application for Gear S (and later S2), which collects the data and sends them to my server via a POST request.

Here is the code for sending the data:

```
$.post(URL_POST_DATA,
        {
    data : JSON.stringify(sendingArray)
        }, 
        function(data, status){
            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $("#status").css("background","green");
            console.log("Success");
        })
        .fail(function(data,status){
            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $("#status").css("background","red");
            console.log("Failure");
            return;
        });
```

Basically, it should turn the background green (as well as putting a log on the console) when the transmission goes successfully, and red if there is a problem. However, the transmission never takes place. There is neither "Success" nor "Failure" on the console.

There are two odd things:

- First, the network log shows it is a GET request.
  [image: Network log shows it is a GET request.]
- Second, the server never receives any request (not a POST or GET), despite being reachable - I checked its reachability by my phone.

Here are the javascript files I include in my application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/idb/idbstore.min.js"></script>
```

Now I wonder whether I am missing something which prevents the transmission request being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine and it should properly work if *the access is provided*. Therefore, by adding the following line in the `config.xml` file, the request was sent successfully.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```